# Iterate through multiple arrays from several folders and perform calculations

Tags: arcpy, raster-calculator, numpy, array

Iterate through multiple arrays, each having multiple arrays
I have three folders, each containing 675 NumPy arrays. I want to iterate over each array in each folder.
My first folder is “Barleyarea,” with several arrays (bar1.npy, bar2.npy, bar3.npy….)
My second folder is “AEIarea,” with several arrays (AEI1.npy, AEI2.npy, AEI3.npy….)
My third folder is “Areagrid,” with several arrays (area1.npy, area 2.npy, area 3.npy….)
I want to iterate over each array and perform the calculation (equation below) for each array when the arrays have a similar filename.
Finalarea1= bar1.npy* AEI1.npy/ area1.npy
Finalarea2= bar2.npy* AEI2.npy/ area2.npy
Finalarea3= bar3.npy* AEI3.npy/ area3.npy

````
#find and print the Path of Bar arrays
file_paths = glob.glob(os.path.join(BarAH, '*.npy'))
array_BarAH = {os.path.basename(f): np.load(f) for f in file_paths}
# print(array_BarAH)
#find and print the Path of AEI arrays
file_paths = glob.glob(os.path.join(AEI, '*.npy'))
array_AEI = {os.path.basename(f): np.load(f) for f in file_paths}
# print(array_dictAEI)
#find and print the Path of Areagrid arrays
file_paths = glob.glob(os.path.join(Areagrid, '*.npy'))
array_Area = {os.path.basename(f): np.load(f) for f in file_paths}
# print(array_Area)
def Barley (array_BarAH, array_AEI, array_Area, array):
    for x , y, z in zip(rray_BarAH, array_AEI, array_Area):
        print(x,y,z)
        bar_st_1= array.append(x*y/z)
        print("Barley step 1 is done")
        bar = []
        Barley(array_BarAH, array_AEI, array_Area,bar )```
````

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment. I updated my question with a bit more explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Consider using [numpy dot function](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwix6qKVpZn8AhU1pekKHaEnCgsQFnoECBUQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fnumpy.org%2Fdoc%2Fstable%2Freference%2Fgenerated%2Fnumpy.dot.html&usg=AOvVaw0HZNSQ83iYzV8H4T_pwCPL) to perform the multiplication in Barley function:

```
def Barley(array_BarAH, array_AEI, array_Area):
    result = []
    for x, y, z in zip(array_BarAH.values(), array_AEI.values(), array_Area.values()):
        result.append(np.dot(x, y) / z)
    return result
```

Answer (score 1):

If the question is how to find and group the npy files you can use [collections.defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#defaultdict-examples):

Folder structure:

[image]

```
import os
import numpy as np
from collections import defaultdict as dd

the_files = dd(list)
main_folder = r"/home/bera/Desktop/GIStest/test/"
for root, folder, files in os.walk(main_folder):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(".npy"):
            fullname= os.path.join(root, file)
            the_files[file.split(".")[0]].append(fullname)
            
for name, filelist in the_files.items():
    print(name+"\n", filelist) #Each item/row is a dictionary with the file name as key and a list of all files with that name as value
    #abc
    # ['/home/bera/Desktop/GIStest/test/B/abc.npy', '/home/bera/Desktop/GIStest/test/C/abc.npy', '/home/bera/Desktop/GIStest/test/A/abc.npy']
    #def
    # ['/home/bera/Desktop/GIStest/test/B/def.npy', '/home/bera/Desktop/GIStest/test/C/def.npy', '/home/bera/Desktop/GIStest/test/A/def.npy']
    
    array_list = [np.load(npyfile) for npyfile in filelist] #From a list of files to a list of arrays
    #[array([[3, 4, 1, 5],
    #        [5, 8, 4, 5]]),
    # array([[5, 6, 6, 6],
    #        [8, 5, 9, 8]]),
    # array([[0, 2, 7, 5],
    #        [4, 4, 6, 7]])]
    #Do something with the arrays...
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I updated my question. Please check it if you have the time.